# Chrome slightly changes alpha-value of RGBA color after setting it

Tags: css, google-chrome, rgba

Please consider the following snippet:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('x');
el.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(124, 181, 236, 0.25)";
alert(el.style.backgroundColor);
```

```html
<div id="x">Testing</div>
```

On Windows 8.1 this gives back the exact input for `backgroundColor` in IE 11 and Firefox 37, but in Chrome 43 it changes the alpha-value, and the alert says:

> rgba(124, 181, 236, 0.247059)

Notice that the alpha-value unexpectedly returns `0.247059` instead of `0.25`.

I've gone through [the `background-color` spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-color) as well as [the rgba spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) and more specifically [the bit about alpha values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#alphavaluedt), but failed to determine whether this is a bug or if the UA (in this case Chrome) is allowed to do this.

**Does any of the relevant specs explain whether Chrome's behavior is "allowed"? As a bonus, can anyone explain *why* Chrome would subtly change the alpha-value?**

---

Footnote: to check if it is the "setter" (`el.style.backgroundColor = ...`) is to blame I've also tried declaring the style on the element inside the DOM itself. This will have the same (unexpected) result. See this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var el = document.getElementById('x');
  alert(el.style.backgroundColor);
});
```

```html
<div id="x" style="background-color: rgba(124, 181, 236, 0.25);">Testing</div>
```

Comment: OK I take the bait and have a look into it. But at a quick glance I wouldn't say the behavior is allowed or not allowed. Its more the JavaScript v8 DOM interaction then CSS error. And I'm speculating that the w3c standards is more concerned with the CSS and doesn't check that the js to dom vs versa is compliant

Comment: @Superfy That's a good comment. I've added a footnote with a slightly different way of *setting* the css value, but there is still a chance the way V8 *gets* the style value is the culprit.

Comment: Your addition is interesting - We would have to delve deeper to see what the Javascript engine is calling - also to note it could be that most other browsers who returns absolute values are simply sending back the string value of RGBA rather then actual rendered value. Because there is no way you can render 0.25 of 8bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thought as RGBA is a represented in 32 bit. That would mean that in actual fact then there is no such thing as an exact **0.25** of the 8 bit alpha. So therefore 0.247059 is the actual correct extrapolated value. So is Chrome Wrong? or is it in fact Correct? and the other browsers are giving you an invalid number that is not the true real representation of what is rendered on the page ?

You can then argue that the W3C standard is not entirely correct and that it should only allow for values that a fully devise-able with an 8 bit Alpha.. But then it is just a recommendation and not law...

Below is a stripped down version of Chromium customised webkit color.cpp code that looks to be doing the color conversions. but then i'm no chromium expert
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code

sources: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/Color.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned RGBA32;

int colorFloatToRGBAByte(float f)
{
    return std::max(0, std::min(static_cast<int>(lroundf(255.0f * f)), 255));
}

RGBA32 makeRGBA32FromFloats(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    cout << "Alpha: " << a;
    return colorFloatToRGBAByte(a) << 24 | colorFloatToRGBAByte(r) << 16 | colorFloatToRGBAByte(g) << 8 | colorFloatToRGBAByte(b);
}

int main()
{
        RGBA32 t;
        t = makeRGBA32FromFloats (255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.25f);
        cout << static_cast<unsigned>(t) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> It's a known issue of Chrome, for quite a long time...

This is due to how Chrome calculates the **computed style** alpha value.

For example your input alpha value is `0.25`.

1. Chrome first transforms it into an 8bit level, `0.25 * 255 = 63.75`.
2. What's weird here is, the number is truncated in to an integer, `63`.
3. Then, Chrome uses the interger to get back to CSS3 color notation,
   `63/255 = 0.24705882352941178`, approximately `0.247059`.

It occurs not only when you set color with JS, but also with CSS. For example:

```
<style>
  div { color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3) }
<style>
<div></div>
<script>
  document.querySelector('div').style.color // rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.298039)
</script>
```